# Run Word from windows service

Tags: windows, ms-word, automation

I'm trying to run Word from cscript witch is runned out from windows service under LOCAL SYSTEM account.

cscript is simple. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

SaveWordAsPDF

Sub SaveWordAsPDF() 


 Dim objWord
 Dim objDocument

 if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
   WScript.Echo "Missing parameters"
end if

 Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 'objWord.Visible = True
 objWord.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
 Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0), 0, True) 
 WScript.Sleep 5000
 objDocument.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 17

 objDocument.Close FALSE
 objWord.Quit
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error "Word could not create the work file. Check the Temp environment variable". All answers from this [Automating MS Word in Server 2012 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323636/automating-ms-word-in-server-2012-r2) topic doesn't help.

Word 2013 x64 
Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.

Comment: If you are going to automate anything that has to do with Word (or Excel, or any other Office app), I strongly suggest using [the official SDK for .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). You will save a lot of work, your code will be easier to maintain, and your application will probbly do whatever it is it does in much less time whenever you call it.

Comment: Also the "Temp environment variable" has to do with your system configuration. You can access the environment config by going to "Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings". Check whether your path variable includes a temp folder or something.

Comment: Try setting a machine-wide TEMP variable in Control Panel...System...Advanced System Setting..Envrionment Variables..  Even if you get past this issue, I'm still concerned that it won't be possible to bring up a GUI window under the Local System account.

Comment: OpenXML DSK doesn't allow all functionality what i needed. Convert to pdf it's only one example which is not allowed by OpenXML SDK. I set TEMP and TMP environment variables. But nothing changed.

Comment: This is [not a supported scenario](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office): *"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."*

Comment: Since you are using "objDocument.SaveAs" I assume you need to open Word to convert documents to a different format. Check for other software that can convert Word documents.